# Kotlin when change value

Tags: kotlin

can i use when in Kotlin to change the value of an existing variable?

i understand this one:

```
val num = 1

val result = when {
    num > 0 -> "positive"
    num < 0 -> "negative"
    else    -> "zero"
}
println(result)
```

should be "positive"

but i want this( psuedo )....

```
val num = 1
var result = "init string"

//bunch of code here
// later....

result = when{
    num > 0 -> "positive"
    num < 0 -> "negative"
    else    -> "zero"
}
```

it writes positive, but it says "Variable "result" initializer is redundant.

What im missing here?
Thx

Answer (score 5):

The line

```kotlin
var result = "init string"
```

is redundant because you leave no possibility of that value not getting overridden in the `when` statement. `"init string"` cannot be printed at the end of the code, the variable will always have one of the three possible values defined in the `when`.

But you can directly initialize `result` with the `when` statement:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    var num = 1

    // directly assign the result of the when statment to the variable
    var result = when {
        num > 0 -> "positive"
        num < 0 -> "negative"
        else    -> "zero"
    }
    
    println(result)
}
```

This prints

```
positive
```

Answer (score 0):

thank you for the answer.

But i can say....

```
fun main() {
var num = 1

// directly assign the result of the when statment to the variable
var result = when {
    num > 0 -> "positive"
    num < 0 -> "negative"
    else    -> "zero"
}

println(result)

// and then later reassign....

num = 2

result = when{
    num == 2 -> "two"
    else -> "not two"
{

println(result)

// prints two
}
```

So i cant reassign an existing string with a when statement, that is not initialized with an another when statement?

I hope this is readable. :)

Thank you.

dagogi